# Tried to call a function and it doesn't work , any suggestion what I'm missing?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I wrote this function and it seemed to work, however when I try to call it shows me an error , function doesn't exist. I'm attaching my select for the calling function under .

USE guitar_shop;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sale_price;

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION sale_price(product_id_input int)

```
RETURNS  decimal (10,2)

DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA
```

BEGIN

declare sale_price_output decimal (10,2);

select

list_price– (list_price * discount_percent *.01)

from products

where product_id = product_id_input

into sale_price_output;

return (sale_price_output);

END //
DELIMITER ;

select  product_name, sale_price(product_id)
from products;

I tried to declare all the variables , and changed the name of function, also I tried to do it by writing set statement the result is the same, function doesn't exist